# Overflow issues with height:100%;

Tags: html, css

[**LIVE CODE**](http://designobvio.us/css/)
I'm trying to have my maincontent div `class="mc"` just appear on the bottom 10% of the screen.  Allowing users to view as much of the background image as possible and still allow the user to see the title of the article.

My solution was to set a `.mc` to 100% height and subtract that from the bottom of the viewports size.  all done in css

**CSS**

```css
.mc { 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    background:#fff; 
    z-index:1; 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:-90%;
}
```

My problem: When content goes larger then 100% height it falls into a void.  I tried min-height; unfortunatly it breaks the code even worse. Scroll to the bottom of [**LIVE CODE**](http://designobvio.us/css/)  to see the problem

or

ERROR'd picture (you can tell it ends from the .box-shadow();)

[image]

---

**Here's the way it should look**
[image: heres a simple mock up]

**HTML**

```
<article class="mc">
<section class="cc">
    <div class="margin_wrapper">
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                <h1 class="at">rocking grass out styles for everyone.</h1>
                <h2 class="ast">The you mice structure for to of almost ability an trying the when designer
                    dissolute that constructing in quickly distinct...</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </header>
        <h3 class="title_header">the good</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <h3 class="title_header">the bad</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <h3 class="title_header">the ugly</h3>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</section>
<aside></aside>
```

Comment: Why no to use some margin or padding? Is this image dynamic?

Comment: Is this image on the background changed programatically or came from a databse? In any case, do you know the height of the image and it will not change?

Comment: I just want a full screen image... heights will change

Comment: the real problem is the text container ending after 100% ... i would like to set it to be min-height:100% but that breaks the layout.  I wanted to use a background-cover feel w/o using background-image.  because it will be set as the featured image in wordpress in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the text container beloow the image and use a negative top margin or negative top with `position: relative` to position the content:

```
margin-top: -10%;
```

or

```
position: relative;
top: -10%;
```

This last method will leave a blank space below the content to the size of the reposition.

Comment: Ugh took a shower and drew it out and figured duhh margin.  thanks rcdmk